# Android view - onAttachedToWindow and onDetachedFromWindow - when are they called in the activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I believe that `onAttachedToWindow()` is called when the `onCreate()`'s `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout.xml)` is called. So can I assume then that in the activity lifecycle that `onDetachedFromWindow()` is called when the activity is destroyed? My question is how do I tie these two call back hooks to the activities lifecycle?

Can I say that `onAttachedToWindow()` is tied to `onCreate()` and `onDetachedFromWindow()` is tied to `onDestroy()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Technically speaking `onAttachedToWindow` is called after `onResume`(and it happens only once perlifecycle).
`ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity` call will add `DecorView` to the current `WindowManger` which will in turn call `WindowManagerGlobal.addView()` which than traverse all the views and call `onAttachedToWindow` on each view.

`onDetachedFromWindow` is tied with `onDestroy`

Comment: question. if its called in onResume then that means everytime the activity resumes the view re - attaches again to the activity ?

Comment: @WenChao That's not true. onAttachedToWindow is called only ONCE per the lifetime of that particular activity.

Comment: @CatalinMorosan, I should state it more clear, you are correct it is called ONCE per lifetime. What I was trying to say is the first(and only) `onAttachedToWindow` happens after `onResume`, there is no more call to `onAttachedToWindow` afterwards in the lifecycle. Thanks.

Comment: @j2emanue I have updated my answer, Views are not re-attached when activity is resumed

Comment: onAttachedToWindow can be called more than once if the view is being used by a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 7):

This is not really an answer but an advice ...

Many times, I've felt the urge to use this method (onDetachedFromWindow) to unregister observers and/or clear scopes...

DO NOT DO THIS!!

onDetachedFromWindow() does not equal Fragment's onDestroyView().

There is no inner method that gets called specifically when the view is destroyed (unfortunately).

onDetachFromWindow() will get called when changing the page in a ViewPager/ViewPager2, while the view is not really being destroyed.
If you use onDetachFromWindow() to clear scopes, you'll either get a NullPointerException, or the view will simply stop responding to updates when scrolling back to the page in question.

The best and easiest thing you could do is use the onDestroyView() method to clear scopes.

The hardest/best way is to listen for the Fragment's LifeCycle (if you want a one time instantiated Adapter), and then dispatch an "destroyed" message through the Adapter to all views observing the Adapter and make them self-unregister themselves.... not even the DataSetObserver class is built to do this (when it should).

Comment: What I've been using is the LifeCycleEventObserver and I still need to manually unregister it on destroy :/, but once the component is fully polished, it becomes extremely scalable.

Answer (score 4):

I find it's possible that `onAttachedToWindow` will be called when `setContentView` is called.

When you use split screen on Android N, and the value of `configChanges` of activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` to be set:

```
 "keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

`onAttachedToWindow` will be called in `setContentView`, because the the variable "mAttachInfo" in the decorview of window is not null, when you call `setContentView` to add `rootView` to `decorView`, `dispatchAttachedToWindow` is called in `addViewInner()`.

Finally after activity `onResume()`, `onAttachedToWindow()` is not be called again.